# How to prevent MKMapView loading from making UITableView choppy

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mapkit

I have a `UITableView` with various different types of custom `UITableViewCell`s.  One of these cells has a `UILabel` for the address and a `MKMapView`.

When the `MKMapView`'s cell is dequeued I pass in an instance of my `Place` model and update the label, create a `MKPointAnnotation`, add the annotation, and set the region.

My problem is this: When the `UITableView` first loads the first few cells (including this map one) the mapView loading its new region blocks the main queue, which stops the tableView from scrolling.  Additionally, since the map loads layers incrementally, after the initial background of the map loads I am able to scroll, but the scrolling is choppy until the map is completely done loading.

I tried putting the `setRegion`, `addAnnotation`, and `centerCoordinate` assignments on a background thread out of curiosity but it makes no difference.  I completely removed this tableViewCell from the tableView and scrolling is clean and chop free.

Does anybody have any suggestions or insight into how to load the mapView without affecting the scrolling in the tableView?

```
class BusinessDetailsAddressTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var addressDetailsContainerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressMapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!

    var place: Place? {
        didSet {
            if let p = self.place {
                self.setUIForPlace(p)
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func setUIForPlace(_ place: Place) {
        self.addressLabel.text = place.address
        self.addressLabel.textColor = Color.grayBackgroundColor

        //Prevent dequeue from resetting map region and coordinates
        if self.addressMapView.annotations.count > 0 { return }
        self.addressMapView.centerCoordinate = place.location
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: place.location, span: span)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = place.location
        self.addressMapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
        self.addressMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also please provide the code on your implementation of using multiple threads?

Comment: @Miket25 I am not using multiple threads for this task - The code above is an exact copy of my actual `UITableViewCell` with only comments removed for readability.

Comment: Do you need the mapview to be interactable or can you use an `MKMapSnapshotter` instead?

Comment: @dan The map does not need to be interactive at all - it just needs to load, center to a particular lat/long, zoom to a particular level, and drop a pin at the center coordinates.  I am not familiar with `MKMapSnapshotter`.

Comment: Unfortunately since it's UI, it can't be placed outside of the main thread, which makes this question more interesting on an optimization stance. I'm curious too how this can appropriately handled?